# Is it possible to make a clamp function shorter than a ternary in JS?

Tags: code-golf, math, tips, javascript

Imagine this short function to clamp a number between 0 and 255:

```js
c = n => n > 0 ? n < 255 ? n : 255 : 0
```

Is this the shortest possible version of a clamp function with JavaScript (without ES.Next features)?

P.S: Not sure if it's relevant but, the 0 and 255 are not random, the idea is to clamp a number as an 8-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to PPCG! Just to be clear, any answer you receive here will not necessarily be a good idea to use in anything except for code golfing. Aside from that, if you care about what version / environment it has to work in you might want to specify it.

Comment: Oh, I'm well aware. I've updated the question a bit. Thank you :)

Comment: Shouldn't you at least remove all the spaces?

Comment: I don't know JS, but one way to clamp is to sort `[0,n,255]` and take the middle element -- might that be shorter?

Comment: @xnor Unfortunately, the JS `sort()` method uses a lexicographical comparison by default, so that would require an explicit callback. (Something [like that](https://tio.run/##fc9BDoMgEEDRfU/hEgzoALE7vIhxgVabNoZpxPT6lGpMDaVlN3n5k@Funsb18@2xcIuXwY/aW103wCyTVdUWDueFEMM6qmvDO9qI1vdoHU5DMeGVjIQLqSjNwivLDE4xbpRE2C2F4ogiRtjbN0Lchss/HIYvPv9jdVyeqPNcyfVfv3ntN/Yv).)

Comment: @Arnauld Wow, that's pretty silly. But it looks like it would be longer even if the sort was numerical.

Comment: I can't imagine a case where a length 1 array would be golfier than the approaches suggested, but just out of interest, JavaScript has built in support for clamped 8 bit unsigned ints: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## 20 bytes

For reference, this is the original version without whitespace and without naming the function:

```javascript
n=>n>0?n<255?n:255:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7PzsA@z8bI1NQ@zwpIWhn8T87PK87PSdXLyU/XSNPQNTQy1tRUAAJ9fQUDLnRJiBRWSQOYHDZJQ2RJQ3RJA5hekKQBul6gMxHSQA6GtBk@aWNkw7Ho1tIyNgL7C7c0WD9E@j8A)

---

## 19 bytes

We can save a byte by inverting the logic of the ternary tests and using `n>>8` to test whether \$n\$ is greater than \$255\$. Because of the bitwise operation, this will however fail for \$n\ge 2^{32}\$.

```javascript
n=>n<0?0:n>>8?255:n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7PxsDewCrPzs7C3sjU1Crvf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGrqGRsaamAhDo6ysYcKFLQqSwShrA5LBJGiJLGqJLGsD0giQN0PUCnYmQBnIwpM3wSRsjG45Ft5aWsRHYX7ilwfqB0mmJmTnF/wE)

---

## 19 bytes

This one returns \$false\$ instead of \$0\$ but works for \$n\ge 2^{32}\$.

```javascript
n=>n>255?255:n>0&&n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc/NCoQgEMDx@z5Fp6igGhX3EGTPEn2xS4xR0eubFVKYNeBh@PFH5l8u5VSNv2GOUdaNanOFuUBBOS/0y1CA76OqJE6yb5JedkEbxISyMPT0pKkHHxsPciIYcyG5IrERTLsh2C0F45q3xXbOz1wvN/6@Mbt@7qijiNH97mfe@4PVCg)

---

## 18 bytes

By combining both versions above, we end up with a function that works for \$256-2^{32}\le n<2^{32}\$ and returns \$false\$ for \$n<0\$.

```javascript
n=>n>>8?n>0&&255:n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7Pzs7CPs/OQE3NyNTUKu9/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmgZQTNdIS8vYSFNTQV9fIS0xM6eYC12JGbISAzRpXUMjY6AMGGCVhklilTZAyGKTNkSVNkSXNkDoB0kbGGC43RRZAZCL6Tn8CoxRrcBiAihooL7ErQBqBiyI/wMA)

#### Commented

```javascript
n =>          // n = input number
  n >> 8 ?    // if n is greater than 255 or n is negative:
    n > 0 &&  //   return false if n is negative
    255       //   or 255 otherwise
  :           // else:
    n         //   return n unchanged
```

(This is a fixed revision of the code proposed by [@ValueInk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink) in the comments.)

---

## 17 bytes

We can go a step further by limiting the valid input range to \$-2^{24}< n\le 2^{24}\$:

```javascript
n=>n>>8?-n>>>24:n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdDRCsIgFIDh@57CS13Y9GyLCGbPImvGQnRk9Pq2pLU0240g338UzlU@pOtuw3inxp57r1pvWmGEOJzodAqoj8Z31jir@522F6wwxVAUUBNCECpLpOSg3SZOOH0nKCQsYcqhCvaPZ8wyWzTHPGaeMlvmX8zSeWia72C6/gT79aCKv8i88FnOWrDl8/7Civ0T)

#### Commented

```javascript
n =>          // n = input number
  n >> 8 ?    // if n is greater than 255 or n is negative:
    -n >>> 24 //   non-arithmetic right-shift of -n by 24 positions
  :           // else:
    n         //   return n unchanged
```

Comment: Why stop there? If you're extremely liberal with what counts as a 0 (as JavaScript tends to do) you can always go for `n=>n>>8?255:n>0&&n` for **18 bytes**, since `false` can be coerced to `0` and this will make all negative numbers evaluate to `false`

Comment: @ValueInk If you don't test \$n<0\$ beforhand, `n>>8` will be truthy for any negative input.